# Hooking into a NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to make a `NSMutableDictionary` and override parts of a default `NSDictionary` in a iOS app. The code I use compiles with no problems, but I am apperently missing something.

I have this `NSLog` of a function :

```
Status: 0x22a1b740> initWithDictionary:{
  ability =     (
                    {
                id = 1001;
            }
        );
        c = 10000;
        l = 1;
        p = 4;
        t = 5;
    }]
```

I tried making a `NSMutableDictionary` to change the key "c" to 20000 with this code;

```
%hook Status
-(id)initWithDictionary:(id)fp8 {
NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSDictionary *oldDict = (NSDictionary *)[fp8 objectAtIndex:0];
[newDict addEntriesFromDictionary:oldDict];
[newDict setObject:@"20000" forKey:@"c"];
[fp8 replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:newDict];
[newDict release];
}
return %orig;
}
%end
```

I get this crash report:

```
May 30 13:02:54 Fangs-iPad ReportCrash[2404]: -[__NSDictionaryI objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x22bd6910
May 30 13:02:54 Fangs-iPad ReportCrash[2404]: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x22bd6910'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x322e73e7 0x3a181963 0x322eaf31 0x322e964d 0x32241208 0x557d98 0x56791c 0x16789d 0x16530f 0x1644dd 0x16851f 0x7af3f 0x340ff471 0x322bc941 0x322bac39 0x322baf93 0x3222e23d 0x3222e0c9 0x35de933b 0x3414a2b9 0x7425f 0x74218)
```

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong here? Would greatly appreciate any help :)

Comment: Google "unrecognized selector" and study several "hits".  Then, if you can't figure it out, come back and explain exactly what you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with this line:

```
NSDictionary *oldDict = (NSDictionary *)[fp8 objectAtIndex:0];
```

fp8 is not an array it is a `NSDictionary`.

So you need something like:

```
-(id)initWithDictionary:(id)fp8
{
   NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
   NSDictionary *oldDict = (NSDictionary *)[(NSArray *)[fp8 objectForKey:@"ability"] objectAtIndex:0];
   [newDict addEntriesFromDictionary:oldDict];
   [newDict setObject:@"20000" forKey:@"c"];
   [fp8 replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:newDict];
   [newDict release];
}
```

Comment: Thanks ALOT for trying, but seems to crash in the same way.

Comment: The dictionarys name is apperently "code" and this is what it contains:

`ability =     (
                    {
                id = 1001;
            }
        );
        c = 10000;
        l = 1;
        p = 4;
        t = 5;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is crashing at this line:

```
NSDictionary *oldDict = (NSDictionary *)[fp8 objectAtIndex:0];
```

here `fp8` is a `NSDictionary` object but you are using it as as `NSArray` object. You can use `objectForKey:` method to retrieve object or this line to get object:

```
NSDictionary *oldDict = (NSDictionary *)[[fp8 allValues] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Otherwise see the structure of `fp8` object because you think it should be an array type object but in actual it's a dictionary.

Comment: The order of objects returned by -[NSDictionary allValues] is undefined and so cannot be relied upon.

Answer (score 0):

`NSDictionary` does not have `objectAtIndex` method. `fp8` is `NSDictionary` and since it is defined as "`id`" compiler will not complain about it. It seems you forgot "**[**" before your dictionary definition where you called the method. It should be `Status: 0x22a1b740> initWithDictionary:[{`.

Comment: The [ is actually before [Status. That part is just from the NSlog, not a partof my hook

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access objects in an `NSDictionary` using `objectAtIndex:` - use `objectForKey:` instead.

If you changed

```
-(id)initWithDictionary:(id)fp8 {
```

to

```
-(id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)fp8 {
```

then Xcode would give you a warning about this.

Comment: Thanks Nick. It does indeed not work if i do 
-(id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)fp8

I actually did that first but changed to id since it didnt compile, bad move to solve the problem I guess...

I basically want to change the dictionary key c by making a NSMutableDIctionary with the edited value, but cant get it to work..